# migrating from javascript to typescript for an angular project

Tags: typescript, migration

I am trying to migrate one of the projects we have written in java script to typescript. To make the migration easy and in stages, I first want to just rename the files from *.js to *.ts as everything should work right away. Although this seems fine during the compile time, I have hit a road block when I try to use the code generated.

The java script code looked like this
    **Module/index.js**

```
exports.App = angular.module('App', []);
```

App was then referenced in services configuration file like this **Services/index.js**

```
var app = require('../Module').App;
```

This worked well with the setup I had. I was using gulp and browserify to do the build.

Now I'm trying to use the same code and use tsify to compile the typescript files that have the same code as js. However the variable app is undefined in services/index.js

I'm using typescript 1.8. I have also added all the relevant typings files.
I have googled enough to know that none of the examples anything related to this. All the examples show only an import, however I could do an import only if have a module. What options do I have to proceed with the migration? Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Your typescript code should look like:

## `Module/index.ts`

```
export const App = angular.module('App', []);
```

## `Services/index.ts`

```
import {App} from "../Module/index";
```

This way if you have anything wrong in your setup you will get a compile time error instead of a runtime one